# "Baby cat" or "baby kitten"?

Tags: meaning

Considering that a *kitten* is a young cat by itself, is it grammatically correct to say "baby kitten"? Or is "baby kitten" awkward as it would mean something like "baby young cat"?

Comment: Kitten means a "baby cat". I think *baby* in baby kitten is a term of endearment.

Comment: Is there a 'teenager' kitten, slightly older than 'baby' but not quite an adult cat? I suppose *baby kitten* can be contrasted with an *older kitten*.

Comment: I agree with @Lawrence. "Kitten" can apply to a fairly large feline (in human terms, "kitten" probably covers "new born" right through to "tween" or even "teenager"). Sometimes the evidence of kittenhood (!?) comes through behaviour where the physical characteristics and size suggest "cat". I think the phrase "baby kitten" is probably just clarifying age. It does feel redundant, though.

Comment: related, loosely: [Why is cat spelt with a 'c' while kitten is spelt with a 'k'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440557/why-is-cat-spelt-with-a-c-while-kitten-is-spelt-with-a-k)

Comment: It is as grammatical as "red car" and "dry water".

Answer (score 6):

Yes, "baby kitten" is allowable. It could be considered somewhat redundant, but it's a sort of redundancy that serves to act as a way of making the phrase more emphatic, e.g., "Look at how cute the baby kittens are!"